# Using (this) to select a specific instance of a class while hovering a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, this

I'm attempting to use jQuery to update the css of a specific instance of the child "slide-atc" class when the user hovers over its parent element of the "slide-block" class.

My only restriction is that I cannot edit the HTML directly. Here is some code that I was trying but I dont think im using .this() correctly

```css
  $(".slide-block").hover(function(){
    $(this).(".slide-atc").css("bottom", "0px");
    }, function(){
    $(this).(".slide-atc").css("bottom", "-70px");
  });
```

```html
<div class="slide-block">
            <div class="slide-atc">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a syntax error: you will need to chain `.find()` in order to select the nested child, i.e.:

```
$(this).find(".slide-atc").css("bottom", "0px");
```

Alternatively, you can provide `this` as a second argument in a jQuery selector:

```
$(".slide-atc", this).css("bottom", "0px");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using "this" without the $ sign.
The word "this" is a reference to the html element in the DOM itself that is the event source. In the other hand "$(this)" is a jQuery wrapper around that element that enables using other jQuery methods.
Also, I think you have an error at line 4 at  as the second parameter is not a background-color.